# iPhone SDK: GameKit and large files + connection lost

Tags: ios, iphone, gamekit, transfer

Since some time I've been playing with GameKit, but now I'm facing really bad difficulties.

I'm going to send through Bluetooth bigger files - 1-2MB. I've already prepared a packets (about 8kB each).

My app works as described on following scheme:

```
iPhone - sending header: file divided into 25 parts
iPod - received header: OK I got it waiting for 25 parts
iPhone - sending part #1
iPod - received part #1 send next
iPhone - sending part #2
iPod - received part #2 send next
...
iPhone - sending part #24
iPod - received part #24 send next
iPhone - sending part #25
iPod receiving part #25 processing file
```

I send both file parts and messages (confirmation of delivery) using:

```
[mSession sendData:data toPeers:mPeers withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

and receiving data:

```
- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context
```

I would like to know how do you deal with some problems that may occur during Bluetooth transmission. Browsing the documentations GKSessionDelegate doesn't give me any info if the data was delivered or not.

In 90% cases the transfer works fine, but sometimes it suddenly stops and doesn't continue without reconnection/restart the app.

I tried to invent a easy solution to set the data again if I won't get the response within 1sec:

```
-(void)sendAgain {
    [self sendData:bufor];
}
-(void)sendData:(NSData *)data {
    bufor = [data retain];

    timeoutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(sendAgain) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [mSession sendData:data toPeers:mPeers withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
}
```

timeOutTimer is invalidated if sender received confirmation of successful delivery of file part. But in fact when I implement this solution there are even more problems with this.

Devices are next to each other on the desk.

How do you deal with problems of "undelivered" data between devices? It's just a tool, but how it could be annoying while developing games?

By the way, sending short chats messages never caused any problem and I'm using the same methods.

In fact the connection get lost very rarely, just the data likes to be lost in the air. I'm already dividing the parts so the size of the data is about 8kb, what really makes the transfer of images really really slow.

Comment: I notice that the docs suggest a 1000 byte limit, and also mentions 95k in another spot but it isn't clear if these are hard limits or what.

Answer (score 2):

The GameKit framework isn't very reliable at this point, even for simple exchange of data for games I work on. I wouldn't use it to transmit large data, you're just asking for headaches.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both "it" and "refulgentis".  Doing this over GK is asking for unreliable execution.  You are better off setting this up over Bonjour and wiFi or having each user download the content from some central offline source.  If your design requires that the big files move from one device to another, you might want to upload them on one side and download them on the other, rather than trying to device-to-device transfer files that large.

Comment: I agree with this user's approach. You could create a basic web application with a RESTful interface (Rails, ftw) to handle all the online data transactions between the devices. At that point, all you would be doing is targeting the webservice for your information (via HTTP requests). You could also still use both (web and gamekit), depending on your file-size needs. The image could be done through the webservice, and the text could be done through gamekit. That way, you would efficiently use each avenue and avoid major bottleneck issues.